# PHP for Site Title

Tags: php

I am trying to make a dynamic title using PHP on my website. My **index.php** open various client pages **client.php**. On these client pages on want the clients name to be shown as the page title.

I open the client page with the following PHP link.

```
<a class="iframe" href="client.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>&Client Name=<?php echo $rows['client_name'] ?>">
```

And here is how I try to carry over the client name as title on **client.php**, but it just comes as a blank title...

```
<?php $client_name_title = $_GET['Client Name'];?> 
<title><?php echo $client_name_title ?></title>
```

What am I doing wrong???

Comment: error might be due to space in key name 'Client Name' try by removing them something like client_name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the variable through the URL without spaces, like so:

```
<a class="iframe" href="client.php?id=<?php echo $rows['id']; ?>&client_name=<?php echo $rows['client_name'] ?>">


<?php 
    if(isset($_GET['client_name'])){
        $client_name_title = $_GET['client_name'];
    } else {
        //client not set, revert to default behavior
    }
?>
```